# Id se guarda con un espacio final en mi MySQL

Tags: php, html, sql

El problema que tengo es que cuando un usuario se registra se guarda el id del usuario en la base de datos con un espacio final (no uso auto_increment porque necesito que sea asi).
El código es tal que este:

```
$idset1 = rand() . "\n";
$idset2 = rand() . "\n";
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { 
    session_start(); 
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['confirmpassword']) && isset($_POST['email'])){

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($_POST['password']));
    $confirmpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($_POST['confirmpassword']));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

    if($password != $confirmpassword){
        die("The confirmation password was not equal to the password.");
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        die("The email entered was not correct.");
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        die("This username already exists.");
    }


    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        die("This email already exists.");
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$idset1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $idset1 = $idset1 + $idset2;
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$idset1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            die("An error ocurred, please retry");
        }
    }

    $ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `date`, `ip`) VALUES ('$idset1', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$date', '$ip')") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `ads_urls` (`acc_id`) VALUES ('$idset1')") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `nodes` (`id_ass`, `active`) VALUES ('$idset1', '0')") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    header("Location: login.php?action=registered");
```

Un saludo ;).
Stackoverflow me pide escribir mas pero creo que no hay nada mas que detallar, salvo lo de que lo hize un poco lio pero bueno tampoco soy profesional es mas un hobby (no he dado clases en mi vida jaja).

Comment: Se que no estoy usando consultas preparadas, es un test y cometi el error de hacerlo asi, antes de sacar la version al mercado corregire ese error y usare consultas preparadas. (las empezare a usar desde ahora)

Comment: Porque concatenas `"\n"` ?

Comment: El espacio se lo agregas tú aquí: `$idset1 = rand() . "\n";
$idset2 = rand() . "\n";` al poner `\n`. Además si la columna debe ser única en cualquier momento `rand` te puede generar un valor que ya exista. No entiendo por qué no usas auto-increment, ¿hay algo que lo justifique?

Comment: Eso lo verifico una vez, y si hay una igual da error, hay una razon, un bug con el phpmyadmin obsoleto del servidor en el que hago test jajaj, si pongo autoincrement funciona a veces y otras te sacas valores aleatorios y sigue sumando , pro ejemplo va 1,2,3 y de repente hace 65,66,67, y la verdad no se porque no me di cuenta de que agrege yo el /n jaja.

Comment: Eso no es ningún bug, cuando intentas insertar una fila por ejemplo y ocurre un error, el valor del auto-increment se aumenta, es un comportamiento normal, para evitar eso hay que verificar que los registros no existen antes de insertarlos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolver esto de dos maneras:

1. Quitando tu mismo los espacios de esas variables cuando las declaras, eliminando la siguiente el siguiente caracter `\n`

   $idset1 = rand() . "";
   $idset2 = rand() . "";
2. Depende de tu motor dentro de la sentencia `INSERT` al pasar los valores puedes quitar los espacios.

Ejemplo SQL Server: LTRIM(RTRIM(@Variable))
Ejemplo ORACLE: TRIM(@Variable)